# Drupal function db_query() stores overflow value for INTs that are not too large

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have this code inside of a exit hook in a custom module:

```
$diff = round(((microtime(true)-$script_start_time)*1000));
watchdog('thaty', $diff);
    if(variable_get('thingy', 0) == 1) {
        $data = array(
           'q'=>$_GET['q'],
           'memory'=>memory_get_peak_usage(),
           'execution_time'=>$diff
        );
        db_query('INSERT INTO {blah} (q,memory,dt,execution_time) VALUES (\'%s\',%b,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),%b)',$data);
    }
```

The value of $diff will occasionally consistently get saved in the database as 2147483647, which is the overflow value for an INT, I believe, in PHP. When I log the value via watchdog I can confirm that it does not get set to 2147483647, but the real value, which is a three digit whole number.

Typical values (confirmed from logging):

- 708
- 408
- 413

The execution_time column is int(11).

I can't seem to find the source of this issue. Things I've tried:

- Using %d instead of %b for the value
- Assigning $diff to a new an INT variable
- Checking for this wrong value pre-insert
- Confirming the value of $diff is not too large for an INT in PHP
- Tried using %n, re: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupocalypse-now-or-dangerous-integer-handling-drupal-write-record

Comment: What type is the execution_time column?

Comment: @Pekka - thanks, added to post. int(11)

Comment: Can you dump the finished query before it gets sent to the server?

Comment: Is there some Drupal way to do this?

Comment: @Justin I don't know (I don't know Drupal well)

Comment: @Pekka - Than I can't easily do this due to the hosting setup. I will if I get really, really, really desperate. (Almost there!)

Comment: @Justin it seems `db_query("INSERT....")` is deprecated in favour of http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_write_record/6 - maybe worth a try?

Comment: @Pekka - Good suggestion. Trying.

Comment: @Justin: Just a guess, but `round()` returns a float, not an int, so there might be some implicit type casting going on that differs between logging and database insertion. Try casting to int explicitly, and use `%d` as the placeholder.

Comment: @Pekka - drupal_write_record seems to have done the trick. If you put an answer in, I'll mark it (pending a few more hours of data to test).

Comment: @Justin: As for checking the resulting query from Drupal, you could try implementing [db_rewrite_sql()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_rewrite_sql/6) and check for your query. Still not necessarily the 'final' query ending up on the server, but some steps later in the processing chain (checking the MySQL logs would certainly be better, if you can manage to get access)

Comment: You can use timer_read instead microtime(true).

Comment: @ya.teck- Never ceases to amaze me the hidden gems I find in the API. Thanks. @Henrick - Great tip, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>It seems db_query("INSERT....") is deprecated in favour of [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_write_record/6).</strike>

Try [drupal_write_record()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_write_record/6).

Seeing as this is most certainly a masking problem when building the query (rather than a database problem), maybe that does it better.

Comment: Using `drupal_write_record` is not a bad idea, but the rest is just wrong. `drupal_write_record`is a convenience function that use db_query itself, which is the standard way of querying in drupal.

Comment: @googletorp I'm no Drupal expert, but according to the source code, `drupal_write_record` does a number of things to the placeholders before doing the `drupal_query()`. One of these things seems to have fixed the issue. Of course it'd be nicer to look at the query to see what was wrong, but this seems to have worked out

Comment: @googletorp yes, and that seems to have fixed the OP's issue so it seems to be fine (Although I'd like to understand what did it in the end, the OP stated he used `%d` instead of `%b` before but to no avail).

Comment: @Pekka, actually it doens't do anything to the placeholders themselves. It just constructs a query very similar to what OP made himself. The difference is that it can use the schema information to fill out default values defined with `hook_schema`, and it will use correct placeholders (%d for INT). Anyways I downvoted you, because you wrote something completely incorrect. `db_query` is the way to create queries and with use of %d, what the OP did should have worked. The real problem could lie in the scheme definition, or OP didn't copy over all the info in the query.

Comment: @Pekka, Reposted comment as I accidentally submitted it while writing it, and spend too long time formulating it to be able to edit it. See you managed to respond before I completed.

Comment: @googletorp yeah, no problem. I got the notion that `db_query("INSERT...")` is deprecated from this comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_query/6#comment-132 if this is incorrect, sorry. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @googletorp I stand by the last sentence of my answer, though: If the column is an INT, and the incoming value is `708`, and `%d` is used, and it gets garbled, the problem must be witht the part that builds the query

Comment: @Pekka: My guess being a seasoned Drupal developer, is that the fault is OP didn't use `%d` or there was some other factor he didn't post. In any regard he got his problem solved and you edited your post (thanks), so I'm good.